# LINQ to Entities Union is throwing an error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have managed to get the following working:

```
var transactions = from t in context.Transactions
                   group t.Create_Date_Time by t.Participation_Id
                       into t1
                   select new { ParticipationId = t1.Key, CreateDateTime = t1.Max() };

var cases = from c in context.Cases
            group c.Create_Date_Time by c.Participation_Id
                into c1
            select new { ParticipationId = c1.Key, CreateDateTime = c1.Max() };

var interactions = from i in context.Interactions
                   join pp in context.Party_Participation on i.Party_Id equals pp.Party_Id
                   group i.Last_Update_Date_Time.HasValue ? i.Last_Update_Date_Time : i.Create_Date_Time
                       by pp.Participation_Id
                       into i1
                   select new { ParticipationId = i1.Key, CreateDateTime = i1.Max() };

transactions.Union(cases);
```

However at last when I was trying to add third output,

```
transactions.Union(interactions);
// or
interactions.Union(transactions);
```

I got the following error

either way it is throwing following error

> Error 1   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#2>'
>   Error 2   'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Union<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

The only difference in third sequence is, I am using join with another table. I have tried `.AsEnumerable()`, `.ToList()` and `.ToArray()`, none of them helped.

Comment: What are the data types of the items in t1, c1, and i1?

Comment: int and datetime
ParticipationId - int
CreateDateTime - datetime

Comment: I would double check the type of ParticipationId and make sure that there isn't a long, or short, or double in there somewhere.  That error is usually caused by the anonymous types not being identical in some way.

Comment: Are you sure they're both int?  I'd hazard a guess that one of them is a short or a long, which is why it's failing.

Comment: @DoctaJonez, Basically the last query is has a join with one more table. Hece it becomes Linq.ParallelQuery. The rest of two queries are Linq.IQueryable. Making union of these two different types are producing error.

Comment: @DoctaJonez, @diceguyd30, I feel the ideal solution would be converting Linq.ParallelQuery to Linq.IQueryable. However I do not know how to do this

Comment: .AsQueryable() would make it into an IQueryable, but I'd be suprised if that fixes it...  The anonymous types must have a different signature for it to be complaining.  Weird.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create `interactions`, its type is not an anonymous type of int and DateTime, it is of int and **nullable** DateTime.  This is because in your inline if statement, you never call `.Value` off of the nullable column.  Your code should work if you create `interactions` like this:

```
var interactions = from i in context.Interactions
                   join pp in context.Party_Participation on i.Party_Id equals pp.Party_Id
                   group i.Last_Update_Date_Time.HasValue ? i.Last_Update_Date_Time.Value : i.Create_Date_Time by
                       pp.Participation_Id
                   into i1
                   select new {ParticipationId = i1.Key, CreateDateTime = i1.Max()};
```

Simpler Example:

```
var lst = new int?[] { 2,3,null,5,5 };
var lst2 = new int[] { 2,3,4,5,6 };

lst.Select(x => x.HasValue ? x.Value : 0).Union(lst2); //works fine
lst.Select(x => x.HasValue ? x : 0).Union(lst2); //throws error
lst.Select(x => x ?? 0).Union(lst2); //also works
```

Even though we can easily see that the inline if statement will never return a null value in either case, the compiler cannot make such guarantees and has to type the return value to that of a nullable int in the second case.

Comment: @diceguyd30, could you provide how to code for this please? I am sorry I am not able to understand the .Value stuff.

Comment: @Elan, The code in my answer is the corrected code.  Replace what you have with it.

Comment: The grouping could be more easily expressed using null coalescing.  `i.Last_Update_Date_Time ?? i.Create_Date_Time`

Comment: @Jeff M  Indeed, you are correct. Edited to show that (if only in my simple example).

Comment: @diceguyd30 Strangely enough, on linqpad, .net 4.0 if i use your simple solution first line `lst.Select(x => x.HasValue ? x.Value : 0); //works fine` it actually returns the nullable version, in my case `Int32?[]`. However, if use the last line `lst.Select(x => x ?? 0); //also works` This returns the expected `Int32[]`. Not sure why that is.

Comment: @Joe Hmmm...I don't seem to get the same result in linqpad. Running this line: `(new int?[] { 2,3,null,5,5 }).Select(x => x.HasValue ? x.Value : 0)` returned an IEnumerable<Int32>  Are you just calling `ToArray` to get the `Int32?[]`? (I ask since the lines you listed return IEnumerables, not arrays)

Comment: @diceguyd30, sorry, reread my comment and it was very misleading. what i meant was `X.HasValue ? X : 0` doesn't work for my scenario where as `X ?? 0` works.  I'm trying to select all ints that belongs to a set. My scenario is `Table.Where(t => aIntList.Contains(t.anInt))`. The `aIntList` is of type `IOrderedQueryable<Int32>` and `t.anInt` has nulls.

Comment: This just fixed my problem.  I didn't realize that one of my database timestamp fields was nullable and the other union table was not null.  This caused the anonymous types to be different.   THANKS for the hint on where to look

Answer (score 0):

Most likely t1.Key and i1.Key are different types.  The anonymous types must have exactly the same property names and types, declared in the same order for you to be able to union them.

As a side note, you probably also want to change this line of your code:

```
transactions.Union(cases);
```

to this:

```
var unionedQuery = transactions.Union(cases);
```

otherwise it won't perform the union, because you've not stored the resulting query.

Comment: That is working for me, the problem 

istransactions.Union(interactions)

Union of interactions is throwing an error

Comment: Just because it didn't throw an error doesn't mean that it works, it can't be returning the unioned results if you haven't stored the resulting unioned IQueryable.

Comment: I guess the ideal solution would be converting Linq.ParallelQuery to Linq.IQueryable. However I do not know how to do this.