# How to convert Linq.ParallelQuery to Linq.IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

```
var transactions = from t in context.Transactions
                               group t.Create_Date_Time by t.Participation_Id
                                   into t1
                                   select new { ParticipationId = t1.Key, CreateDateTime = t1.Max() };

            var cases = from c in context.Cases
                        group c.Create_Date_Time by c.Participation_Id
                            into c1
                            select new { ParticipationId = c1.Key, CreateDateTime = c1.Max() };

            var interactions = (from i in context.Interactions
                               join pp in context.Party_Participation on i.Party_Id equals pp.Party_Id
                               group i.Last_Update_Date_Time.HasValue ? i.Last_Update_Date_Time : i.Create_Date_Time by
                                   pp.Participation_Id
                               into i1
                               select new {ParticipationId = i1.Key, CreateDateTime = i1.Max()}).AsQueryable();
```

Considering the above code, following will work

```
transactions.Union(cases);
```

However following will not work

```
transactions.Union(interactions);
```

Because transactions and cases both are returning `Linq.IQueryable` but the last one is `Linq.ParallelQuery` due to it join with an another table.

I need this functionality basically to make Union. `interactions.Union(transactions)` or  `transactions.Union(interactions)` one with other.

Comment: did you try interactions.Union(transactions), it should work

Comment: @KIvanov unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: try interactions.Union(transactions.AsEnumerable());

Comment: @KIvanov, no luck mate, again the same error
Error 1 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<AnonymousType#2>' 
Error 2 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Union<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer to this question may be incorrect however I raised up this question primarly for the following problem.
[LINQ to Entities Union is throwing an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972943/linq-to-entities-union-is-throwing-an-error).

I found a fantastic reply from  [diceguyd30](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464094/diceguyd30) and it was solved my problem. Hence I am closing this question in response to my previous question's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The anonymous type of `transactions` and `cases` is the same. The anonymous type of `interactions` is **different**!

So the solution is to `select` in a way that makes the anonymous types the same. So either create your own type or convert the select product's properties to the same type.

Something like this should produce the same anonymous type for all the selects:

```
select new { ParticipationId = (int)c1.Key, CreateDateTime = (DateTime)c1.Max() }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interactions.Union(transactions.AsEnumerable());
```

that should work since the first parameter is `IQueryable` and the second is `IEnumerable`

```
Queryable.Union<TSource> Method (IQueryable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource>)
```

Comment: @K Ivanov, no it is throwing following error.

Error 1 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<AnonymousType#2>'
Error 2 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Union<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: the prob with .AsEnumerable() is that it will execute the query and bring all the data

Comment: whats the relationship between Interactions and Party_Participation, is it 1-to-Many or else?