# Join Query using Entity FrameWork with Union

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to C# and EF  and I am in trouble with a table with multiple queries ,I am trying to get all fields in query 1 and 2, in one grid which have no relationship among them.

```
private class DataBindingProjection2
    {
        public int ApmntID { get; set; }
        public int NId { get; set; }
        public int Emp { get; set; }
        public DateTime InTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime OutTime { get; set; }
        public int price { get; set; }

    }



Data.ODDBEntities2 We = new Data.ODDBEntities2();

string date = dateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek.ToString();


var q3 = (from c in We.NonRegularDetails
                    where c.Date.Value == dateTimePicker1.Value
                    select new DataBindingProjection { ApmntID = c.ApmntID, NId = c.NID, Emp = c.Emp, InTime = c.InTime.Value, OutTime = c.OutTime.Value, price = 345 }).Union(from c in We.RegularAppDetails
                    where c.day == date
                    select new DataBindingProjection2 { ApmntID = (int)c.ApmntID, NId = c.RID, Emp = c.EmpId, InTime = c.InTime.Value, OutTime = c.OutTime.Value, price = 345 }).Select(c => new { c.ApmntID, c.NId, c.Emp, c.InTime, c.OutTime, price = 345 }).OrderBy(d =>d.ApmntID);

        var users = q3.ToList();
```

I get the error in the union saying

[image]

so what I am doing wrong?

And is there a good way to do this?

These 2 queries work fine alone !!

Comment: Check at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972943/linq-to-entities-union-is-throwing-an-error

Comment: You're trying to union `IQueryable<DataBindingProjection>` with `IQueryable<DataBindingProjection2>`, which isn't possible. It isn't clear, why do you need `DataBindingProjection` and `DataBindingProjection2` at all. You could make the projections as anonymous types, and join them.

Comment: @Sameer - it gives the same error - http://prntscr.com/2myzg8

Comment: I think that your problem here is type mismatch : `query` is of the type `DataBindingProjection` and `q2` is of the type `DataBindingProjection2` this is why union gives error. If you want to union group keys, select the keys of your groups `var q3 = query.Select(x => x.ApmntID).Union(q2.Select(x => x.ApmntID));`

Comment: @Dennis - ok, i will try tnx bro :D

Comment: @Sameer `(from a in We.NonRegularDetails
                      where a.Date.Value == dateTimePicker1.Value
                      select new { ApmntID = a.ApmntID, NId = a.NID, Emp = a.Emp, InTime = a.InTime.Value, OutTime = a.OutTime.Value, price = 345 }).Union(from b in We.RegularAppDetails
                      where b.day == date
                      select new { ApmntID = (int)b.ApmntID, NId = b.RID, Emp = b.EmpId, InTime = b.InTime.Value, OutTime = b.OutTime.Value, price = 345 }).Select(c => new { c.ApmntID, c.NId, c.Emp, c.InTime, c.OutTime, price = 345 }).OrderBy(d => d.ApmntID);
`

Comment: @Dennis i change the code as above to make the mismatch ok. but it give only the result of 2nd query. am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: @Archangle: could you post changed code?

Comment: @Dennis if i make the projections as anonymous type can i use "union" ? [link] http://prntscr.com/2mzghq

Comment: @Archangle: you anonymous types are different: compare `a.Emp` and `c.EmpId`

Comment: @Dennis ok, i make it right :D . yap, there was same difference in types and same other bugs in it  , and thx for all the help bro !

Comment: @Sameer ok, i make it right . tnx bro for helping me !!